# Kotlin Error with Conditional Statements Selecting Images

Tags: android, kotlin, mapping

**Overview**

I'm trying to add a custom layout to an Android Spinner control so that it will have an image followed directly by some text.
However, there are over two-hundred rows that will be added to the spinner, so I'm using a function to obtain the proper resource (mipmap or drawable) image.
I have a custom adapter for the Spinner, which works fine.

**Problem**

The project will not build and always crashes inside the function that chooses the appropriate image (although at a different line every single time). The basic setup of the function/conditional is included below.

The error message is not very clear:

```
e: org.jetbrains.kotlin.util.KotlinFrontEndException: Exception while analyzing expression at (821,13) in...
```

**Solution**

If I was to make a guess, it's because there are too many resources inside the conditional statement and too much memory is getting used up.

**Question**

Is there a more efficient way to handle adding these resources/images to the spinner (i.e., switch statement, mapping, etc.)?

```
    val every_team_arr = arrayOf<String>("Team 1", "Team 2", "Team 3", ...) // Over 200 teams in total
```

In the override fun onCreate() function:

```
    var team_list = ArrayList<Team>()
    for (team in every_team_arr)
    {
        team_list.add(Team(team, getEveryTeamImage(team)))
    }
```

Here is the function and conditional that chooses the appropriate image. This is where the error happens, at a different place every time.

```
fun getEveryTeamImage(team: String): Int {
    if (team == "Team 1") {
        return R.drawable.team_1
    }
    else if (team == "Team 2") {
        return R.drawable.team_2
    }
    else if (team == "Team 3") {
        return R.drawable.team_3
    }
    else if (team == "Team 4") {
        return R.drawable.team_4
    }
```

Comment: Can you post code lines pointed by expection? (821,13). What is there?

Comment: The line number changes every different time I attempt to run the code. However, they always point to the return statement inside the conditional (i.e., return R.drawable.team_3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `String` array, you should define an enum. By the example I expect that for each team name corresponds to single drawable resource. Then, you could do:

```
enum class Team(val name: String, @DrawableRes val image: Int) {
    TEAM_1("Team 1", R.drawable.team_1),
    TEAM_2("Team 2", R.drawable.team_2),
    TEAM_3("Team 3", R.drawable.team_3)
    // ...
}
```

Then you can access team list as follows:

```
val teams = enumValues<Team>()
```

This way you omit if statement altogether.

Later, assuming that you need `String` array for your adapter, you can do this:

```
val teamTitles = teams.map { it.name }.toTypedArray()
```

And then, say you picked a title, thus you have single `String` value, you can find corresponding team this way:

```
val selectedTeam = teams.find { it.name == selectedName }
val image = selectedTeam.image
```

Comment: This worked fantastically. Thank you very much for your help.